# How to properly configure a TCP inboundAdapter with QueueChannel and ServiceActivator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to configure a TCP socket that receives data in the format `name,value` in distinct messages. Those messages arrive on average every second, sometimes faster or sometimes slower.

I was able to set up a working configuration but I am lacking a basic understanding of what actually is happening in Spring Integration.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class TCPSocketServerConfig
{
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow server(
        final CSVProcessingService csvProcessingService,
        @Value("${tcp.socket.server.port}") final int port
    )
    {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Tcp.inboundAdapter(
                Tcp.nioServer(port)
                   .deserializer(serializer())
                   .leaveOpen(true)
            )
               .autoStartup(true)
               .outputChannel(queueChannel())
        ).transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer())
         .handle(csvProcessingService)
         .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller()
    {
        return Pollers.fixedDelay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel queueChannel()
    {
        return MessageChannels.queue("queue", 50).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ByteArrayLfSerializer serializer()
    {
        final ByteArrayLfSerializer serializer = new ByteArrayLfSerializer();

        serializer.setMaxMessageSize(10240);

        return serializer;
    }
}
```

And the `CSVProcessingService` looks like this (abbreviated):

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CSVProcessingService
{
    @ServiceActivator
    public void process(final String message)
    {
        log.debug("DATA RECEIVED: \n" + message);
        final CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        final CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(CSVParameter.class);

        if (StringUtils.contains(message, StringUtils.LF))
        {
            processMultiLineInput(message, csvMapper, csvSchema);
        }
        else
        {
            processSingleLineInput(message, csvMapper, csvSchema);
        }
    }
}
```

My goals for this configuration are the following:

- receive messages on the configured port
- withstand a higher load without losing messages
- deserialize the messages
- put them into the queue channel
- (ideally also log errors)
- the queue channel is polled every 50 ms and the message from the queue channel passed to the `ObjectToStringTransformer`
- after the transformer the converted message is passed to the `CSVProcessingService` for further processing

Did I achieve all those goals correctly or did I make a mistake because I misunderstood Spring Integration? Would it be possible to combine the `Poller` and the `@ServiceActivator` somehow?

Futhermore, I have a problem visualizing how my configured IntegrationFlow actually "flows", maybe somebody can help me to better understand this.

**EDIT:**

I reworked my configuration after Artems comment. It now look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class TCPSocketServerConfig
{
    @Value("${tcp.socket.server.port}") int port;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow server(
        final CSVProcessingService csvProcessingService
    )
    {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Tcp.inboundAdapter(
                tcpNioServer()
            )
               .autoStartup(true)
               .errorChannel(errorChannel())
        )
         .transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer())
         .handle(csvProcessingService)
         .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory tcpNioServer()
    {
        return Tcp.nioServer(port)
                  .deserializer(serializer())
                  .leaveOpen(true)
                  .taskExecutor(
                      new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 20,
                                             30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                             new SynchronousQueue<>(),
                                             new DefaultThreadFactory("TCP-POOL"))
                  ).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel()
    {
        return MessageChannels.direct("errors").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandling()
    {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel()).log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ByteArrayLfSerializer serializer()
    {
        final ByteArrayLfSerializer serializer = new ByteArrayLfSerializer();

        serializer.setMaxMessageSize(10240);

        return serializer;
    }
}
```

I also removed the `@ServiceActivator` annotation form the `CSVProcessingService#process` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what confuses you, but your configuration and logic looks good.

You may miss the fact that you don't need a `QueueChannel` in between, since an `AbstractConnectionFactory.processNioSelections()` is already multi-threaded and it schedules a task to read a message from the socket. So, you only need is to configure an appropriate `Executor` for `Tcp.nioServer()`. Although it is an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` by default anyway.

On the other hand with in-memory `QueueChannel` you indeed may lose messages because they are already read from the network.

When you do Java DSL, you should consider to use `poller()` option on the endpoint. The `@Poller` will work on the `@ServiceActivator` if you have `inputChannel` attribute over there, but using the same in the `handle()` will override that `inputChannel`, so your `@Poller` won't be applied. Don't confuse yourself with mixing Java DSL and annotation configuration!

Everything else is good in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I reworked my configuration according to your explanations and added error handling which hopefully works and makes sense.